# Arduino I can't make this statement work

Tags: arduino-uno

```
int val1 = 0;
byte val2 = 10;
int buttonPin = A0;
byte result = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
    val1 = digitalRead(buttonPin);

    if (buttonPin == HIGH) {
        result = result + val2;
        result = result + 10;
    } 
    else
    {
        digitalWrite(val1, LOW);
    }

    Serial.print("STATE   ");
    Serial.print(val1);
    Serial.print("    ");
    Serial.print(result);
    Serial.println();

    delay(100);
}
```

Comment: why did you post the code? ... what does the title of your post mean?

Comment: I trying to increase the value of result by 10 every time when the button is high

Comment: you have not said what is the problem ... it is like taking your automobile to a mechanic and saying "it has a problem" ... what do you think that the mechanic would repair?

Comment: what does `button is high` mean?

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of putting additional information in a comment. You don't want to waste our time, do you? You hope that we think about your problem. BTW, what is your question?

Comment: One problem of your code is  that you are comparing the pin number of the button to HIGH, instead of the read button state. Will write an answer, when you made your question more clear, since I think this will not solve your problem completely

Comment: I'm sorry to say that your code is a complete train wreck. I know, you're still learning, but there's so many errors there that even a novice who had spent just a few minutes reading the documentation and examples would have avoided that it's just completely unrecoverable.

Answer (score 3):

I appears you want to increment the result by val2 each time the button is pressed.  If you want to wire it up this way you can but there are potential issues with this, such as not catching each time you press the button, or thinking you pressed the button twice when you accidentally held it down for more than 100ms.  The code for this method is below:

```
const int buttonPin = A0;
bool buttonState = LOW;
int val = 10;
int result = 0;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(buttonPin,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
    buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

    if (buttonState == HIGH)
    {
        result = result + val;
    } 

    Serial.print("STATE:   ");
    Serial.print(buttonState);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print("RESULT:  ");
    Serial.print(result);
    Serial.println();

    delay(100);
}
```

The way to prevent double counts or missing counts would be to use interrupts.  Later I may write that one up if you need that instead.

Good Luck!

Comment: I use void function to increase value. Thanks for you guys help